# How to use environment variables in the Cmd arguments of dockerode?

Tags: node.js, docker

**The code below prints out:** `??? $VAR`

**I was expecting/hoping for:** `??? ttslkfjsdalkfj`

```
container.exec(
  {
    Cmd: ['echo', 'test $VAR'],
    Env: ['VAR=ttslkfjsdalkfj'],
    AttachStdout: true,
    AttachStderr: true,
  },
  (err, exec) => {
    err && console.error(err);
    exec.start({ hijack: true, stdin: false }, function(err, stream) {
      docker.modem.demuxStream(stream, process.stdout, process.stderr);
    });
  },
);
```

Thanks for any help and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute a shell that interperpates the variables, rather than the `echo` binary.

```
Cmd: ['sh','-c','echo test $VAR']
```

You can emulate both commands via the command line on a container without an entrypoint:

```
○→ docker run -e VAR=testa debian echo test '$VAR'
test $VAR

○→ docker run -e VAR=testa debian sh -c 'echo test $VAR'
test testa
```